# Can I create a mutual login system for multiple windows store apps?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have multiple windows store apps of a company and all of them have signing in option. What I am trying to do is create a mutual login system for all of my apps. In simple words, If user log into one app then he automatically signed in other apps.

I am using sqlite locally to maintain user's session data. So, I tried to access the one App sqlite file from other app by giving a static path to its installed location. But it won't open the sqlite file.

Can I put this sqlite file in any folder where other apps can access it too? 
Is there any common folder/storage space in windows store app where other apps will be able to access this sqlite file?

Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: *No mobile OS* allows one app to access the data of another app. Windows Phone allows you to specify and use a [Workplace account](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/accounts-and-billing/what-is-a-workplace-account). What are you trying to do?

Comment: What I am trying to do is one time login for all of my windows store app not windows phone app. If user logged into one app then it automatically log into other apps.

Comment: For non-work authentication, the easiest way would be to authenticate using the phone's [Microsoft Account](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-single-sign-on/).

Comment: Oops, didn't notice. The same holds though. Eg. there is a tutorial on [using Microsoft Account](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-single-sign-on/) for authentication that is almoste *exactly* the same as the Windows Phone article. Enterprise authentication is even easier. A list of available authentication options can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh750301.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I'll explore Microsoft Account authentication and get back to u shortly

Comment: it's not going to allow OP to do what he wants to. MS Authentication needs each app to log in separately. The question specifically stated that he wants to avoid doing this

Comment: Also check the [Authentication and User Identity](Authentication and User Identity) section. It seems apps already have access to a `Credential Locker` to securely store passwords. There are also other options, eg sharing certificates between applications that use certificate authentication

Comment: @roryok not so. Applications that have permission to access the user's identity already know the user's Microsoft account. You can't even install an app without this account

Comment: I may be mixing it up with the OneDrive / Live services account

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to authenticate user with my server not with Microsoft account.....because I send many parameters along with login credentials.....

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't help right now, Windows 10 does have a solution for apps from the same publisher sharing data. You can use [`ApplicationData.GetPublisherCacheFolder(folderName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder.aspx) to get access to one or more folders that you share amongst your apps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no common storage between apps. The best you can do is to store the sqlite file somewhere locally (let the user choose) and then hold permission to access that file in the [MostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.mostrecentlyusedlist.aspx)

This will allow your app to access it at any time. However, the user will have to manually open the file at least once with each app that needs to use the login.

The only way I can think of to do what you're trying to do *without* user interaction would be to write your own server backend and use the IP address / user agent string and other variables to uniquely identify a device. When the device logs in then all other requests from that device would be considered "logged in" until the user logs out from one of them.

This would be very insecure and I would not recommend it. Anyone could impersonate the user if they knew enough about the device they were using, and were behind the same router.

Comment: I don't think any of this is needed - Microsoft already provides authentication services through its [Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-single-sign-on/)

Comment: see my comment on the question regarding this. MS auth needs a login from each separate app.

Comment: Check the links. There are multiple services and authentication options provided,including tutorials eg on implementing your own shared certificate authentication. The corporate app scenario is one of the main use cases of Windows Phone